# Why did the author write such a difficult answer? (Michael Spivak "Combined Answer Book for Calculus Third and Fourth Editions") Any intent?

Tags: inequality, soft-question

I am reading "Calculus 4th Edition" by Michael Spivak.

The following problem is Problem 16. (b) on p.17 in this book.

> 16. (b) Using the fact that $$x^2+2xy+y^2=(x+y)^2\geq 0,$$ show that $4x^2+6xy+4y^2>0$ unless $x$ and $y$ are both $0$.

I solved this problem as follows:

> Let $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$.
> Then, $4x^2+6xy+4y^2=(x^2+y^2)+3(x+y)^2\geq x^2+y^2>0$ since $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$.

I think my solution is very easy.
But I feel the author's answer for this problem is difficult and strange.

The following answer is from "Combined Answer Book for Calculus Third and Fourth Editions" by Michael Spivak.

> 16. (b) The first equation implies that $$4x^2+8xy+4y^2\geq 0.$$
>     Suppose that we also had $$4x^2+6xy+4y^2\leq 0.$$
>     Subtracting the second from the first would give $2xy\geq 0$. If neither $x$ nor $y$ is $0$, this means that we must have $2xy>0$; but this implies that $4x^2+6xy+4y^2 > 0$, a contradiction.
>     Moreover, it is clear that if one of $x$ and $y$ is $0$, but not the other, then we also have $4x^2+6xy+4y^2> 0$.

Why did the author write such a difficult and strange answer?
Any intent?

Comment: Sometimes a specific approach is used in solving one problem that is also a hint for how to approach later problems.  That doesn't seem to be especially applicable in this case though.  This one seems more like the author had a specific approach in mind and used it.

Comment: @abiessu Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: It's also possible that the author of the problem  had one solution in mind and the author of the solution found a different one.

Comment: The second seems a reasonable approach for someone not used to methods that are often used in contest math type or who had forgotten such methods after several years of undergraduate/graduate level study in commutative algebra, algebraic and general topology, measure theory, Banach spaces, etc. The approach is reasonable because such a person wouldn't be used to the types of school algebra tools that could be applied, and thus proof by contradiction is a non-tricky beginning, and also happens to allow one to plow through. It's probably how I would have solved it in the 1970s and 1980s . . .

Comment: That said, I would probably wonder at the purpose of the hint, and possibly might then have stumbled on the first approach. But this requires one to think about completing the square in contexts outside of quadratic equation solving and putting conic equations into standard form, and if one had never before seen the approach in the first method ever used anywhere, then I think coming up with would be a pretty strong creative leap. It's likely the person who wrote the solutions was a graduate student in math who fits the profile of what I gave in the first sentence of my previous comment.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thank you very much for your comments.